# Listview C# - WPF form fixed letter

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My question is that I have listview in my project, the listview will add items from the database but I want to get a € .... (... is the value of the database). How can I add in a WPF form always this symbol € and how can I line it out right. Thanks for helping!

```
gridV.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Vorderingen < 1j",
    Width = 100,
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("VorderingenKT")
}); 

gridV.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Voorraden",
    Width = 100,
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Voorraden")
});

data.GetData();

foreach (Data c in data.Data)
{
    lstData.Items.Add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the currency symbol you need to add a StringFormat specifier to your DisplayMemberBinding.  You might also have to specify the Language attribute on your ListView if the current culture doesn't match the currency symbol that you want to use.

```
// Override language settings if needed to get the designed currency symbol
listview.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("nl");

// Add column using currency format
gridV.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Voorraden",
    Width = 100,
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Voorraden") { StringFormat = "C" }
});
```

If you want everything in the column to be right-aligned then that's a little trickier.  Instead of using the DisplayMemberBinding, your GridViewColumn will need a cell template.  The cell template should include a fixed-width text box with its TextAlignment property set.

Comment: { StringFormat = "C" }, if I add this than only the C will come but not anymore the values from my database

Comment: If the currency format specifier ("C") isn't working then the underlying data type is probably text instead of numeric.  You'll need to either hard-code the currency symbol (see the other answer to this question) or change the data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use String formatting with `DisplayMemberBinding`

```
 DisplayMemberBinding.StringFormat = "€{0}"
```